# Pwa wrong to consider api cache instead of db?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, progressive-web-apps

im building a specific book reader like app.

Main page call api/booksList and receive the json array containing each book info like:

```
[ {  id: server_db_id,  title: "title test",  sum: 10 , date: ... }
]
```

ans its cached after the request, so im not saving the book list into indexedDB, localStorage or other storage. If i need one specific book, i just call the api book list again and filter it. Is that bad design? (book will be over 200 items)

Whe user open the book, it call the `/api/book/book_id` and its cached too, the opened book response is a json list of the lines  of the book, eg:

```
[
 {  
  id: ...
  content: "This is line...lore ipsum..."
  ....
 }
]
```

I put the api response inside vue data variable and the component is rendered correclty

Im not using any kind of handler for keeping this offline by my hand. To detect if user already opened this book, i just call the api, check if errors happened or the responde body has content.

Is that a wrong, bad or stupid decision? Will this hit the quota limit api or other kind of limitation? The "gods" of pwa will raise the finger to me and say: WAAAT. (im not using indexedDB at first because it need some models handling and i want to make things easier if possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I my self was just researching this and concluded, at the moment I am going to go with this method, where I use `cache` for assets, `js, css, html` etc based on their matching routes.

Then when it comes to data e.g. `json` requests etc. Its best to store them in indexedDB (or an equivalent), which really does not require a model or schema as such.

See Jake Archibald's IndexedDB-Promise library https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb its really simple to get your head round.

Though both Jake and Addy say it's not a defacto rule, so you can decide ultimately what is best for you.

### Read this for better clarification

- https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/live-data-in-the-service-worker
- https://medium.com/dev-channel/offline-storage-for-progressive-web-apps-70d52695513c

It helped me to make a better decision on how to go about moving forward.

### Recommendations Also

- Check out PWA Training: https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa
- Workbox: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox (This has sped up my development massively!)
- Codelabs: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/ (Search PWA)

The guides on here are really good at taking you through everything you need.

Good Luck with your PWA

### Random thought (edit)

One thing that makes me question this though is based on some of the examples and guides I have seen is that, data storage is handled in a more ad-hoc manner. For example, if the PWA calls out an API, there are two methods I have come across where you can either manage cached data in the application or in the service worker, e.g. if your API calls to get JSON fails in the app, it can revert to getting data in the indexedDB which hopefully was pre-cached the first time your app called the API.

Or you can use `self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => { ad-hoc stuff here })` this is where you can match either an asset, or data request and hijack the response with either a cache or indexedDB response. Which prevents the need handle offline data in your app.

The first method makes me feel uneasy so i'm gonna go with the addEventListener approach both in the service worker cause thats what it is there for plus my app does not then have to worry about that.

Comment: Wowww, thanks the answer, i will take a look and re-post here, thx